# $gcd(a,b)$ in a UFD subring is not a greatest common divisor in the ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, factoring

Give a counterexample that $R$ is a unique factorization domain but not a principal ideal domain, $S$ is a ring containing $R$,  such that $a,b\in R$, $gcd(a,b)$ in $R$ is not  a greatest common divisor of $a,b$ in $S$.

Comment: I don't understand your wording. What is the proposition to which you desire a counterexample. For example, could you phrase your question as "Give a counterexample to the following proposition... (proposition here)..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\gcd(2,x)=1$ in $\,\Bbb Z[x],$ but the gcd $\,= 2\,$ in $\,\Bbb Z[x/2]$